# Angular: connecting to @Output in mat-stepper

Tags: angular

I'm trying to trigger a callback when Angular Material's Stepper tries to change steps. I see from [the doc](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api) that this is supported, but I must be connecting to it improperly:

From the doc:

```
@Output('interacted')
interactedStream: EventEmitter<CdkStep> // Emits when the user has attempted to move away from the step.
```

My component html:

```html
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear stepper (selectionChange)="onStepChange($event)">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-step label="A" [stepControl]="aFormGroup" (interacted)="onStepperInteracted($event)"</mat-step>
    <mat-step label="B" [stepControl]="bFormGroup" (interacted)="onStepperInteracted($event)"></mat-step>
  </form>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

My compontent ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor () {
    /* define form, aFormGroup, bFormGroup... */
  }

  onStepChange(evt: StepperSelectionEvent): void {
    console.log('step change');
  }

  onStepperInteracted(interactedStream: any): void {
    console.log('interacted', interactedStream);
  }
}
```

How should I connect to the `@Output('interacted')`? When I move from step A to step B, my `onStepChange` function fires, but my `onStepperInteracted` function does not.

I'm on Angular 11.2.5

Comment: Will it work with `(interactedStream)="onStepperInteracted($event)"` ?

Comment: Thanks @user776686 but I've tried that also. The result is the same

Comment: What version of material are you using? I think this was added in version 12, so if you're using older version that won't be available.

Comment: @TotallyNewb thanks. I'm using Angular 11.2.5. You may be right about version issues, and I'm looking for some indication of where support was added for this feature. Do you know where I can verify that?

Comment: @TotallyNewb found it. Looks like you've hit the nail on the head. Thanks!